# How to write (<*>) using (=<<) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

Could someone explain why the following representation of `(<*>)`  with `(=<<)` works:

```
f <*> a = (\f' -> return . f' =<< a) =<< f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This strikes me as a deliberately obtuse way of writing it. Whoever gave you this code is trying to mess with you. Here's the usual definition of `ap`, which is clean and easy to understand:

```
ap f a = do
    f' <- f
    a' <- a
    return (f' a')
```

We can run this through the usual `do` desugaring transformation, replacing `<-` with `>>=`:

```
ap f a =
    f >>= \f' ->
    a >>= \a' ->
    return (f' a')
```

Now, note that the innermost term is `\a' -> return (f' a')`, which can be written as `return . f'`.

```
ap f a =
    f >>= \f' ->
    a >>= return . f'
```

Then, since `(=<<) = flip (>>=)`, we can replace `>>=` with `=<<` by exchanging the arguments:

```
ap f a = f >>= (\f' -> return . f' =<< a)  -- reverse inner bind
ap f a = (\f' -> return . f' =<< a) =<< f  -- reverse the other bind
```

There you go.

Comment: Thanks, it was the way it was asked in a problem. This does make it all much clearer.

Comment: Also `a >>= return . f'` is equivalent to `f' <$> a`, so the whole thing could also be `f >>= (<$> a)`

Answer (score 3):

The use of names `f` and `a` is extremely confusing, because names are suggestive ("f" evokes "function", but isn't). Primed names can be confusing as well. Parens shouldn't be omitted while you're still learning and are unsure about the default operator precedences. Same goes for `do`'s optional curly braces and semicolons.

The two names should have been  `fs` and `as`. Changing them could be part of the expected answer. Thus you have

```
fs <*> as = (\f -> (return . f) =<< as) =<< fs
          = fs >>= (\f ->
            as >>= (return . f))                -- by definition of >>= and =<<
          = fs >>= (\f ->
            as >>= (\a -> (return . f) a))      -- by "eta expansion"
          = fs >>= (\f ->
            as >>= (\a -> return (f a)))        -- by `(.)` reduction
          = do { f <- fs 
               ; a <- as 
               ; return (f a) }                 -- by `do` syntax definition
```

because that's how the `do` syntax is defined. And that *is* [the definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#ap) of [`ap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap), which `<*>` is supposed to be a stand-in for.

It goes without saying that this works only for a type which is not just an Applicative, but a Monad as well.

With *monad comprehensions*, the last one is written

```
          = [f a | f <- fs, a <- as]
```

which is pretty clear in itself.

Comment: Vote Yess For Ness

Comment: @naomik I... I... no words. :)